# Have the following summations been studied before?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-geometry

Suppose $q^2-4pr<0$, and consider the set of integral points

$$\mathcal Z=\{(X,Y)\in\mathbb Z^2:$$
$$px^2+qxy+ry^2+sx+ty+u=0\}$$

which lie on an ellipse. Then define $$M=\sum_{(X,Y)\in\mathcal Z}\alpha X+\beta Y$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ are non-negative integers.

> Are there tools to bound $M$?

> Are there bounds on $M$ using $p,q,r,s,t,u,|\mathcal Z|,\alpha,\beta$?

Having four non-cyclic integral points will determine the ellipse and perhaps control the bounds.

**Conjecture** Given $p,q,r,s,t,u$ and $\alpha,\beta$ there is a formula parameterized by any four non-cyclic integral points $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4\in\mathbb Z^2$ on the ellipse which provides exact value of $M$.

Comment: The first equation. This is the Pell equation. By making such a substitution. $x=x+ay$ , $y=x+by$ You can use this formula later. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1049910___4

Comment: The Pell Equation is for integer points on hyperbolas, and this is an ellipse.

Comment: A nice test case is $(x+1)^2+(x+1)y+y^2=91$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2Bx%20y%2By%5E2%3D91%20in%20integers